# setName to TreeNode (primefaces) after adding an object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree, treenode

I want to like to setName of a node when the user pushes the button of Adding the node will take the name of this object as a labelName so this is the code of the button:

```
public void makeCube() {

        cubeService.create_cube(cubUpdate);


    }
```

and this is my TreeNode :

```
 <p:tree id="tree1" value="#{treeBean.model}"
                        var="node"
                       dynamic="true"
                        selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" onNodeClick="selectNode(node);"
                        >
                    <p:ajax event="select"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}"  />

                    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}" />
                    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeCollapse}" />


                    <p:treeNode type="#{NodeType.CUBE_TYPE}"   >
                        <h:outputText id="cubName" value="#{node}" onclick="selectNode(this); "   />
                    </p:treeNode>
  </p:tree>
```

and finally, this is my form that the user will put the name of an object and when he clicks in "Add" that should save the object and get his name to set it as a name of labelName of the Node.

```
<h:form id="form2" >


        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelCube"> 

        <p:outputLabel value="Name :" for="name_cube"/>
            <p:inputText id ="name_cube" value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.name_cube}" required="true"/>
        <p:outputLabel value="Description :" for="description_cube"/>
            <p:inputText id ="description_cube" value="#{cubeMan.cubUpdate.description_cube}" required="true"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{cubeMan.makeCube()}" update=":formCube" > 

     </p:commandButton>

     </h:form>
```

---

I had to do this code to change the label name with a button in the same form:

```
public void changeName(){

        String res =selectedNode.getData().toString();

        if(selectedNode.getData().toString() !=null){
            res=cubMang.cubUpdate.getName_cube();

            TreeNode  node0 = new DefaultTreeNode(new TreeNodeType().getCUBE_TYPE(),res, null);


    }
```

and in my xhtml page I put this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add tst" actionListener="#{treeBean.changeName()}"  update=":form1:tree1:cubName" />
```

and for the Treenode I put this:

```
<h:form id="form1">


                <p:tree id="tree1" value="#{treeBean.model}"
                        var="node"
                       dynamic="true"
                        selectionMode="single"
                        selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" onNodeClick="selectNode(node);"
                        >
                    <p:ajax event="select"  listener="#{treeBean.onNodeSelect}"  />

                    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}" />
                    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeCollapse}" />


                    <p:treeNode type="#{NodeType.CUBE_TYPE}"   >
                        <h:outputText id="cubName" value="#{node}"  onclick="selectNode(this); "   />
                    </p:treeNode>
   </p:tree>
```

but when I click the button nothing happens but when I click into the tree to make a new node of the last same type it takes the new name. So what should I do to correct this?

Comment: What is the problem then? Does the create_cube method work? Do you have problems updating the tree? which one is it?

Comment: the methode create_cube work but i can't find the way to update the label name of the node after i add the object into my database cause i should pick the name of the object and put it in the nodeName label after the action of creat_cube

Comment: is updating the whole tree a viable solution or do you want to update the new particular node?

Comment: yes jut the node selected it will take the name of the object after click in the button add